# How to provide user id to proxied services in an API gateway pattern?

Tags: api, microservices, api-gateway

I'm making code examples of how to start a modern microservices web architecture from scratch, and I only recently learned about API gateway pattern. So far, the authentication methods I used for microservices were either duplicated in every service or centralized via an internal auth service, called inside the other services.

I think i understand the pattern and benefit well, however I'm stuck at rolling my own example (in rust, where I don't think existing implementations are easy to find) about how to provide the user id to the microservices that are being proxied by the gateway.

Since I suppose we would prefer microservices to be restful and log their access request parameters without unecessarily cluttering them systematically with auth data, I'm making the assumption a good practice should be to pass the user id through request headers, which is agnostic of request method, don't clutter the query parameters, and can be read on a per-need basis.

If a given microservice need to query additional permissions on the user, this would be done separately.

Is this assumption correct, or am I missing something ? What are considered best practices to provide the user info on API gateway pattern ?